# LinkGenerator GetPathByPage doesn't return full Uri

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the LinkGenerator in my EmailSender Service inside an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project.  It was first returning Null values until I figured out that I needed to include the area in the definition.  However, the Url still doesn't provide the server information that I was expecting.

It generates the Url looks like this:  `"/Identity/Account/Login...`"

I expected this: `"https://{hostName}/Identity/Account/Login..."`

My work around is to concatenate values from the httpContextAccessor as posted.  But, this seems hokey.  Can someone give me direction as how this is supposed to work?

Work around (not great):

```
var callbackUrl = $"{httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://" +
                  $"{httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host}" +
                  linkGenerator.GetPathByPage(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,
                            "/Account/Login", null, new {area = "Identity", userId = user.Id});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By design `linkGenerator.GetPathByPage` will return the relative path.If you need the full `Uri` including `Scheme` and `Host` then you have to use another method `GetUriByPage` also provided by `LinkGenerator` as follows:

```
var callbackUrl = linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,
    "/Account/Login", null, new {area = "Identity", userId = user.Id});
```

Comment: That is correct sir.  As said by the late, great Dr. Smart.  "Missed it by that much".  Thanks much.